# VS 2010 Debugging From Network Drive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging

I am having an issue with a WPF application I am building.  All development files are located on a Network Drive.  No, there is no option to move them to my development machine (I have a small SSD... no jokes please ;-)).

The issue I am having is getting VS to debug the application.  I hit debug, and it goes through the build process, and just stops.   I see a 'Build Successful" message in the status at the bottom, but that's it...  no debugging happens, the application does not fire up, etc...   Yes, the application works, I am able to verify simply by running the app from the /bin/debug location.

I have tried adding the:

```
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true">
```

to devenv.exe.config.

I have also tried the caspol stuff as stated in other posts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974612/edit-and-run-net-projects-from-network-shares) to enable FullTrust to -allcode, as well as the networked drive itself, and nothing changes.

Please help...  I really need to be able to debug!!!

Comment: One thing to note, I just opened another project from the network (a new project actually), and this is the first time I actually got a message stating: "The project file XXXX may have come from a location that isn't fully trusted...blah blah blah"    This is even though I have done and re-done the caspol tricks for both .Net v2, and v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face.  for some reason all dev files are symlinks.  I needed to enable FullTrust:

```
fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation L2L:1 R2R:1 L2R:1 R2L:1
```