# Visual Studio 2008 can't write to network drive

Tags: visual-studio-2008, permissions, vmware-workstation, network-drive

I'm unable to modify code on a mapped network drive through VS2008, whether it's running as me or as administrator. Outside of VS I can edit the files with no problem. I'm running Windows 7 on vmware and the network drive maps to a location on the ubuntu linux host.

I'm stuck and have no idea what to try (other than relocating the code into the virtual machine, but I don't want to do that because they need to be accessible from ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the user/group ownership settings on the host Linux file system. Once I got that sorted out it worked fine. So it was an issue with the host system, not an issue with Visual Studio or Windows 7 running on the vmware.

Answer (score 0):

The network drive is not trusted. 
see the following links for discussios:
[Edit and run .NET projects from network shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974612/edit-and-run-net-projects-from-network-shares)
[The Project Location is Not Trusted error in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603144/the-project-location-is-not-trusted-error-in-visual-studio)

I am aware that there has been significant changes in the support tools for visual studio in this area, for example there is no longer the mmc snap in that allowed you to do this security configuration

Comment: Doesn't work for me, and the error message I get doesn't say anything about trust. E.g. "You don't have permission to save in this location" or "unable to save..." But I certainly do have permission.

Comment: sorry, I don't have access to a network drive to troubleshoot. Have you tried increasing the sucurity level of your local intranet in internet explorer?

Comment: I tried loosening internet/intranet security settings. Didn't work.